# Getting an ARC warning for capturing an ojbect strongly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC and getting a warning saying `Capturing 'request' strongly in this block is likely to a retain cycle.`

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        self.appointmentArray = [responseString JSONValue];
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fix warning "Capturing \[an object\] strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle" in ARC-enabled code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205128/fix-warning-capturing-an-object-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming `request` is declared somewhere before the blocks. You need to declare it as `__weak`, or set a second, weakly-declared variable to it.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7205301/1600) is similar. Try this:

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
__weak ASIHTTPRequest *request_b = request;
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSString *responseString = [request_b responseString];
    self.appointmentArray = [responseString JSONValue];
}];
[request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request_b error];
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}];
```

Comment: Right now I'm declaring it like `__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];`

Comment: Under ARC, `__block` variables are writable within blocks, but are implicitly `__strong`.

Answer (score 6):

Simply replacing:
**__block** ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

with:
**__weak** ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

will suffice.

Comment: That only works if you're targeting iOS 5, which probably isn't a good idea right now.

Comment: For iOS4 use __unsafe_unretained instead of __weak.

Comment: +1 for solving my problem: __weak GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];