# ios block w/self = endless loop

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to do

```
__weak UIButton *ptr = self.backBtn;
self.footer.defaultSelectedItem.selectionBlock = ^{
    [ptr sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
};
```

and I'm getting an infinite loop on my code anyway.

I've already referred to:

- [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352561/retain-cycle-on-self-with-blocks&ei=Bh9qT66VNMGrsQKF57SXCQ&usg=AFQjCNHZv6KWEsDnxZz1C3BpAO2ZdWzaDQ&sig2=UBGLb818jgTMKMdfsHP1Lw)
- [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCsQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205128/fix-warning-capturing-an-object-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a&ei=Bh9qT66VNMGrsQKF57SXCQ&usg=AFQjCNFnOlVdGlvFfqt6PgEFwZgRQYN2fQ&sig2=S-lZgt5oWsdr7LYKOB6llg)
- [and this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api&ei=Bh9qT66VNMGrsQKF57SXCQ&usg=AFQjCNEbq1UCEHyKKxjJG2HghsjyFoF9Dw&sig2=tuNRMKb1w7ChCL2h4vpMyA)

With no promising result. My program still hangs and then after a minute xcode dumps out a huge loop cycle once I run out of memory. What should I do?

**EDIT**

I should have also pointed out that I'm using `Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your block have a flag to tell it not to execute:

```
 __block BOOL flag = NO;
 .... = ^{
      if (flag) return;

      flag = YES;
      // rest of block code here.
      flag = NO;
};
```

Comment: seems like a work-around to the problem. but it's a working work-around so I will take it. +1