# Warning: Capturing $XXX strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle in 'AFHTTPClient.m'

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, warnings, afnetworking

I use `AFNetworking` in my project,but it have 2 warnings here:
[image: warning]

full warning string is:

`/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m:575:38: Capturing 'operation' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle`

Comment: The problem is that your block will retain the operation object, which in turn retains the block, and thus they will never be released and you'll have a memory leak. Why are you assigning that inside there? you already have the `operation` object available

Comment: it is one of `AFNetworking`'s files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853915/how-do-i-avoid-capturing-self-in-blocks-when-implementing-an-api) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205128/fix-warning-capturing-an-object-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a) with very good answers about this issue. This is an issue with using strong variables within blocks. To counteract this when using ARC you must use the `__weak` declaration. I recommend you read the first link  especially to learn more.

EDIT

At first I didn't realize you were seeing this warning in AFNetworking's code. Using the most recent version of AFNetworking I do not see this warning.

Comment: yes,I downloaded AFNetworking yesterday,it work fine,just have 2 warnings.

Comment: Warnings about this block issue? Are you using the most up–to-date version of Xcode?