# capturing self strongly in this block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have found this solution to resolve this issue with block [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556605/capturing-self-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a-retain-cycle)

but seems there is another problem as well. Please check screenshot to understand my problem.

[image]

how to resolve it?

Comment: Please copy/paste your code instead of a screenshot ( where the interesting parts are hidden).

Comment: `__weak MyTypeName * weakSelf = self;`

Comment: or... `__weak __typeof(&*self)weakSelf = self;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should technically use `__weak` after the type per [Apple's Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)

I usually write it like this:

```
__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
```

Comment: also I have IBOutletCollection that I am accessing in the block how do I need to use it?

Comment: The same way you'd access another property on self: `weakSelf.myOutletCollection`.