# How to setup reachability test for specific domain through AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager *mgr=[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager];
[mgr startMonitoring];

[mgr setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
//NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
    if ([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable) {
        NSLog(@" ONLINE");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"OFFLINE");
    }

}];
```

This is how I tested reachability through AFNetworking now! How to check reachability in specific domain? And how does  AFNetworking uses to test the reachability ?

[AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.google.com"]; didn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things.

First, you really should configure the manager **before** starting monitoring. In this case this means you should call `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock` before calling `startMonitoring`.

Second, when you're creating new `AFNetworkReachabilityManager` by using `managerForDomain:`, you are responsible for managing lifetime of the object. If you use code above with ARC enabled, `mgr` will be deallocated as soon as it goes out of scope meaning that there will be no manager to monitor reachability. One solution is to make `mgr` an instance variable of a class, e.g. an application delegate.

Comment: As you suggested I created instance variable in Appdelegate like @property(strong ,nonatomic)AFNetworkReachabilityManager *mgr; and initialized mgr with mgr=[AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.google.com"]; in appDidFinishLaunching. Now the block is running but it's showing offline. What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you also updated your status change block to use `mgr` instead of `sharedManager`? If yes, then I don't know what the problem is. Try using different domain perhaps to see if it's an issue with google.com.

Comment: Thanks a ton Andrey! I missed that. Solved the issue but if we use mgr instead of [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.google.com"] in if condition inside the block, it will show retain cycle warning! even if i declare mgr as @property(strong ,nonatomic)__block AFNetworkReachabilityManager *mgr; Can u suggest me about it.

Comment: For breaking retain cycles please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14556706/1524700.

Answer (score 1):

/**
 Creates and returns a network reachability manager for the specified domain.

@param domain The domain used to evaluate network reachability.

@return An initialized network reachability manager, actively monitoring the specified domain.
 */
+ (instancetype)managerForDomain:(NSString *)domain;

this is from the afnetworking source code, 
to monitor a specified domain, just create a reachability manager for that domain using this class method. like this

```
AFNetworkReachabilityManager *mgr= [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"www.google.com"];
```