# Declaring a Block In a Super Class That Can Be Accessed By Subclasses

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I have a **BaseViewController** which contains a property of type block:

```
typedef void (^result)(BOOL didSend);

@class ShakeView;

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController

@property result mPlayerControlResultHandler;

@end
```

I want that this block can be accessible by other subclasses. So in `viewDidLoad` of **BaseViewController** I did this to initialise the block:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _mPlayerControlResultHandler = ^(BOOL didSend)
    {
        if(!didSend)
        {
            __block BaseViewController *blocksafeSelf = self;

            [blocksafeSelf onOperatingSpeakerShortConnectionFailure];
        }
    };
}
```

This would throw a warning

> Capturing self strongly in this block is likely to lead a retain cycle

So I searched for a solution this and tried everything suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14556605/capturing-self-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a-retain-cycle) but still unable to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the BaseViewController retains the block, and the block retains the objects it references, referring to `self` in the block causes a retain cycle.

The block doesn't modify the value of self, so it needn't be qualified with `__block`.  Instead, it should be declared weak and moved outside of the block:

```
__weak BaseViewController *blocksafeSelf = self;

_mPlayerControlResultHandler = ^(BOOL didSend)
{
    if(!didSend)
    {
        [blocksafeSelf onOperatingSpeakerShortConnectionFailure];
    }
};
```