# Strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

I create the custom cell with the activity indicator view
With using the SDWebImage I hidden the activity indicator when the image is downloaded

```
[customCell.userPhotoImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[thisNotify user]imageURL]] placeholderImage:nil completed:^
 (UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
 {
     customCell.activityView.hidden = TRUE;
 }];
```

But I execute the code I look this warning

Capturing 'customCell' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this just before that block call:

```
__weak UICustomCell * weakCustomCell = customCell;
[customCell.userPhotoImageView setImageWithURL:....^{
   weakCustomCell.activityView.hidden = YES;
}];
```

I think that will fix the error. You just assign a new weakly referenced object to your cell, which should prevent the retain cycle. Not entirely sure of the reasoning behind it, but worth a shot.

*edit* [here's a potential explanation though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7205128/fix-warning-capturing-an-object-strongly-in-this-block-is-likely-to-lead-to-a)